# Woocommerce - Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted error

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am working in woocommerce and i have created brands and categories. For brands i have created custom taxonomy in woocommerce. When admin will enter the products then he will choose the brand and then category of product.On front end I am showing all brands on brand page and when user clicks o any brand then showing all categories of that brand. In this first the brand will fetch all products and then categories of that product. This is my code to get categories of a brand. This code was working fine but there are more than 50,000 products and now it is showing memory related error. Do i need to change in the query because i have increased php memory limit in wordpress and php.ini.

Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 20480 bytes) in

```
$subCatArr = get_related_cat_taxo($taxonomy='brands', $term_id, $relatedCat='product_cat' ); 
            $rows = ceil(count($subCatArr) / 3); 
            $rowsConst = $rows;
            $rows = 0; // for first div.
            $first = true; 
            foreach($subCatArr as $key=>$value): 

                $term = get_term_by('id', $value, 'product_cat', 'ARRAY_A');
                $child_term = get_term( $value, 'product_cat' );
                $parent_term = get_term( $child_term->parent, 'product_cat' );
                if($parent_term)
                {
                    $catUrl =  site_url()."/product-category/".$brandSlug.'/'.$parent_term->slug.'/'.$term['slug'];
                }else{
                    $catUrl =  site_url()."/product-category/".$brandSlug.$term['slug']; 
                }   
                if ($rows == 0): 
                    $rows = $rowsConst;
                    if (!$first) {
                        echo "</ul>\n";
                    } else {
                        $first = false;
                    }   

                echo '<ul class="alphabeticall_list_5col">';
                ?>
                <?php //echo get_category_link( $value ); ?>
                <li> <a href="<?php echo $catUrl; ?>"><?php echo get_cat_name( $value ); ?></a></li>
                <? else: ?> 
                <li> <a href="<?php echo $catUrl; ?>"><?php echo get_cat_name( $value ) ?></a></li>
            <?php 
            endif;
            $rows--;
            endforeach;
        ?> 

    this is function in function.php file

    function get_related_cat_taxo($taxonomy, $term_id, $relatedCat) { 

        $args = array( 
               'post_type' => 'product', 
               'post_status' =>'publish', 
               //'posts_per_page'   => -1,
               'tax_query' => array( 
                'relation' => 'AND',  
                   array( 
                      'taxonomy' => $taxonomy, 
                      'field' => 'id', 
                      'terms' => array($term_id), 
                      'include_children' => false, 
                      'operator' => 'IN' 
                   ), 
                ) 
            );
            $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
            $subCatArr = array();
            //if( $loop->have_posts() ) : 
            while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); 
            global $product; 
            //now get the another category of the product..
            $post_id = get_the_ID();
            //get the category of this particular product 
            $term_list = wp_get_post_terms($post_id, $relatedCat, array('fields'=>'ids','order'=>'DESC',));
            foreach( $term_list as $value ){
                if( array_search( $value, $subCatArr, true ) === false ){  
                    array_push( $subCatArr, $value );
                }
            }
            endwhile; 
            wp_reset_postdata();   
            if (($key = array_search($term_id, $subCatArr)) !== false) { 
                array_splice($subCatArr, $key, 1);
            }

            return $subCatArr;
    }
```

Comment: try debugging to see which part consumes the most memory this will help you to determine the problem block.

Comment: how i can check this by using microtime() function?

Comment: place this line echo memory_get_usage() . "\n";  after each independent block of code this will show you how much memory was consumed.

Comment: before while loop it is showing "257553520" and after loop "169050920"

Comment: WP_Query is taking more Memory in use: 257553304 (245.62202453613M)

Comment: May be you can begin to replace: `global $product;  $post_id = get_the_ID();` by `$post_id = $loop->post->ID;` … you should also uncomment `if( $loop->have_posts() ) : ` and then add after `endwhile;` an `endif;` … I don't know if this will low your memory usage. You should paginate to avoid this running on 50000 products each time...

Comment: Is the error allowed memory limit in the file `woocommerce-pdf-invoices-packing-slips/includes/class-wcpdf-main.php` ? 

if yes try to make DIR `wpo_wcpdf` inside `/wp-content/uploads`. 

this error may occur during the init_tmp() process.